# How to create horizontal scroll bar for a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following items.

```
left arrow  slide1 slide2 slide3 slide4 slide5... right arrow
```

I want to be able to have `horizontal` scroll bar in my div.

I have something like this

```
<section id='slide-container'>
        <div id='left-nav'><a href='#'><img src='images/left-nav.png'/></a></div>
        <ul id='slide-list'>
            <li><img src='images/slide1.png' /></li>
            <li><img src='images/slide2.png' /></li>
            <li><img src='images/slide3.png' /></li>
            <li><img src='images/slide4.png' /></li>
            <li><img src='images/slide5.png' /></li>
            <li><img src='images/slide1.png' /></li>
            <li><img src='images/slide2.png' /></li>
            <li><img src='images/slide3.png' /></li>
            <li><img src='images/slide4.png' /></li>
            <li><img src='images/slide5.png' /></li>
        </ul>       
    </section>
```

css

```
#slide-container{ 
    width: 970px;
    height: 190px;  
    line-height: 190px;
    border:solid 1px #EEEEEE;
    position: relative;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

I can only see the vertical scroll bar and my slides are vertically aligned. I was hoping someone here can help me to keep my slides aligned horizontally and show a scroll bar for it.

My brain is fried...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `#slide-container` add `white-space: nowrap; overflow: auto;`.

For `#slide-list li` add `display: inline-block;`.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your style with this

```
   #slide-container{ 
    width: 970px;
    height: 190px;  
    line-height: 190px;
    border:solid 1px #EEEEEE;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    display:block;
}
#slide-list
{
    width:1500px; /*i put this for see the scrolling/*
}
```